# JQuery dialog, how was the "explode" effect created

Tags: javascript, jquery

This may seem like a strange question, but, for the JQuery `dialog()` method, they have (amongst others) a `hide` effect called `explode`?

Can anyone tell me how they would create such an effect? Such as - Do they do it by manipulating pixels on the screen? If so, *how* do you manipulate pixels on the screen that way? I know JQuery is written in JavaScript, so I would like to know just the *basics* of how you can do something like that in JavaScript.

I ask this because, eventually I would like to be able to create my own custom effects.
Thanks!

Comment: Here's the source code: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.effect-explode.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source code is actually pretty straightforward and clear, I'll try to do some summary:

1. decide how many pieces (N) should the source element be broken to
2. on the beginning clone the source element N-times, wrap them into "overflow hidden" divs and position content and created div, so the final visual is same as original element
3. hide the original element
4. move (animate) each piece separately to simulate "explosion"

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for breaking that down for me ejzy!